# pandas how to check differences between column values are within a range or not in each group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `df`,

```
cluster_id    date
1             2018-01-02
1             2018-02-01
1             2018-03-30
2             2018-04-01
2             2018-04-23
2             2018-05-18
3             2018-06-01
3             2018-07-30
3             2018-09-30
```

I like to create a boolean column `recur_pmt`, which is set to `True` if all differences between consecutive values of `date` in each cluster (`df.groupby('cluster_id')`) are `30 < x < 40`; and `False` otherwise. So the result is like,

```
cluster_id    date          recur_pmt
1             2018-01-02    False
1             2018-02-01    False
1             2018-03-30    False
2             2018-04-01    True
2             2018-04-23    True
2             2018-05-18    True
3             2018-06-01    False
3             2018-07-30    False
3             2018-09-30    False
```

I tried

```
df['recur_pmt'] = df.groupby('cluster_id')['date'].apply(
            lambda x: (20 < x.diff().dropna().dt.days < 40).all())
```

but it did not work. I am also wondering can it use `transform` as well in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform` with [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) and parameter `inclusive=False`:

```
df['recur_pmt'] = df.groupby('cluster_id')['date'].transform(
            lambda x: (x.diff().dropna().dt.days.between(20, 40, inclusive=False)).all())
print (df)
   cluster_id       date  recur_pmt
0           1 2018-01-02      False
1           1 2018-02-01      False
2           1 2018-03-30      False
3           2 2018-04-01       True
4           2 2018-04-23       True
5           2 2018-05-18       True
6           3 2018-06-01      False
7           3 2018-07-30      False
8           3 2018-09-30      False
```